# Reading numbers from file to string to array

Tags: c++

I am reading numbers from a file, say:

1 2 3 4 5

I want to read this data from a file into a string into an array for further processing. Here's what I've done:

```
float *ar = nullptr;
while (getline(inFile, line))
{
    ar = new float[line.length()];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
          stringstream ss(line);
          ss >> ar[i];
    }
}
unsigned int arsize = sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0]);
delete ar;
```

Suffice it to say that it works insofar it only gets the first value from the file. How do I get the array to be input ALL the values? I debugged the program and I can confirm that line has all the necessary values; but the float array doesn't. Please help, thanks!

Comment: `std::vector<float> v; float f; while (inFile >> f) { v.push_back(f); }`

Comment: You're doing `new[]` but `delete` not `delete[]`.... _yikes_! And `sizeof(ar)` is not what you think it is!! What's wrong with `std::vector`? It prevents basic mistakes like this.

Comment: (So, in short, "but the float array doesn't" - _yes it does_ but your `arsize` is wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

`line.length()` is the number of characters in the line, not the number of words/numbers/whatevers.

Use a vector, which can be easily resized, rather than trying to juggle pointers.

```
std::vector<float> ar;
std::stringstream ss(line);
float value;
while (ss >> value) {     // or (inFile >> value) if you don't care about lines
    ar.push_back(value);
}
```

The size is now available as `ar.size()`; your use of `sizeof` wouldn't work since `ar` is a pointer, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use the standard library and its streams.

```
$ cat test.data
1.2 2.4 3 4 5
```

Given the file you can use the stream library like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::ifstream file("./test.data", std::ios::in);

  std::vector<float> res(std::istream_iterator<float>(file),
                         (std::istream_iterator<float>()));

  // and print it to the standard out
  std::copy(std::begin(res), std::end(res),
            std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, "\n"));

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem earlier when I wanted to extract data line by line from a file to fill my sql database that I wanted to use. 
There are many solutions to this specific problem such as:

**The solution is using stringstream with a while statement to put data from file into the array with a while statement**

**//EDIT**

1. While statement with getline

//This solution isn't very complex and is pretty easy to use.

**New Improved simple solution:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>   
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{       
    ifstream line;
    line.open("__FILENAME__");
    string s;
    vector<string> lines;
    while(getline(line, s)) 
    {
        lines.push_back(s);
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < lines.size();i++)
    {
        cout << lines[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

compiled code to check - http://ideone.com/kBX45a

Comment: Why do you read a value in `i` and then overwrite it with uninitialized data? `g = array[4];` is out of bounds.

Comment: array[4] has 5 values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 how can it be out of bounds?

Comment: array[4] has 4 values. The clue is in the 4.

Comment: array[0] can hold a value

Comment: array[0], array[1], array[2] and array[3] can hold values. array[4] cannot hold a value. Please complete some tutorials.

Comment: why can't it hold a value, what makes it go out of bound?

Comment: Thanks I just realized that

Comment: foo[0] == 16, foo[1] == 2, foo[2] == 77, foo[3] == 40, foo[4] = 12071. no foo[5]

Comment: Your assignments are the wrong way around for the array version.

Comment: please clarify and explain what you mean by "wrong way around" and what you mean by array version.

Comment: I have fixed my code and I tested it with strings and it has worked.

Answer (score -2):

What about `atof`?

```
std::string value = "1.5";
auto converted = atof ( value.c_str() );
```

Rather complete:

```
while ( std::getline ( string ) ) 
{
   std::vector < std::string > splitted;
   boost::split ( splitted, line, boost::is_any_of ( " " ) );

   std::vector < double > values;       
   for ( auto const& str: splitted ) {
      auto value = atof ( str.c_str() );
      values.push_back ( value );
   }
}
```

Comment: Didnt downvote but this is needlessly complicated, `operator>>` skips whitespace for you by default.

Comment: @Borgleader you are completely right. This is a more general solution.